# Grunt sass @import not making css

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to use sass with grunt and I'm having a weird behavior.
If I create any file with underscore it doesn't work anymore, and it doesn't import either.

That is my Gruntfile, really simple:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: 'scss/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        },
        sass: {
            example: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'public/css/app.css': 'scss/**/*.{scss,sass}'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

If I create a file, for example, `application.scss` in `scss/`, it works and creates the file `app.css` in `public/css`, but if I create any file with underscore, for instance: `_variables` in `scss/` it doesn't work anymore, it doesn't create the file or changes anything and it doesn't import either.

application.scss:

```
@import "variables";

body {
    background-color: $bg-color;
}
```

_variables.scss:

```
$bg-color: red;
```

Answer (score 2):

Files with names starting with an underscore are considered as partial in the eyes of SASS. This means that SASS would not make an actual css file out of them. To prevent this, either create an `index.scss` file and import your partials in it or remove the underscore from their names.

[Official DOcs](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4)

Comment: I did and I tried to import and doesn't work anyway. And the `application.scss` is the main file, the thing is that if I create any file with underscore in that folder it doesn't work anymore, even if it's only to be imported.

Comment: I edited the question. there you will see how I'm trying to import.

Comment: It just doesn't work, it only works if I delete the `_variables` file from the folder.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you also need to change `'public/css/app.css': 'scss/**/*.{scss,sass}'` to `'public/css/app.css': 'scss/index.scss'` and reference your other sass files in index.scss, that way grunt-sass will process sass from that one file, that file imports all the other parts.

Comment: @suzumakes - Doing this I won't be able to create other files, I will be watching for all, but compiling only one, what if I have to create other file like: `gallery.scss`?

Comment: `index.scss` has `@import 'gallery';` in it. You edit `_gallery.scss` and when grunt runs on `index.scss` it will compile the _partial sass file_ `_gallery.scss` into it. `index.scss` _imports_ `_gallery.scss` and the resulting CSS file has _all_ the rules you put in both files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'scss',
    src: '**/*.{scss,sass}',
    dest: 'public/css',
    ext: '.css'
}]
```